# Angular Data From API Not Working as Expected

Tags: angular

I am working on a weather application on Angular 4 and i got the data from an API. This is my code for the searvice that fetches the data from the API

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
@Injectable()

export class WeatherService{
    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getWeather(location){
    return(this.http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5`/weather?q=${location}&APPID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`));
   }
}
```

And in another component am requesting for the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from "../shared/services/weather.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private weatherdata;
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) { }
  city = "";
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getWeather():void{
    this.weatherService.getWeather(this.city)
    .map((data) => data["_body"])
    .subscribe((data) => this.weatherdata = data);
  }
}
```

I see all the data when i try to console.log the data in the subscribe() function as:

```
{"coord":{"lon":3.4,"lat":6.45},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":297.883,"pressure":1023.84,"humidity":100,"temp_min":297.883,"temp_max":297.883,"sea_level":1028.6,"grnd_level":1023.84},"wind":{"speed":4.16,"deg":240.504},"rain":{"3h":3.935},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1501330679,"sys":{"message":0.0021,"country":"NG","sunrise":1501306837,"sunset":1501351501},"id":2332459,"name":"Lagos","cod":200}
```

, but when i try interpolating `{{weatherdata.name}}` in my HTML its empty, anything am doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect to get with `{{weathername.data}}` ? I don't see anything like that in your response? Nor that you would have a variable named `weathername`?

Comment: Am sorry, i meant {{weatherdata.name}}

Comment: I expected it to be "London"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing now, you are getting the string value of your response when you get data like so:

```
.map((data) => data["_body"])
```

You want the JSON instead:

```
.map((data) => data.json())
```